# Python: How to NOT wait for a thread to finish to carry on?

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have some code that waits for X to happen, then creates a thread and does processEmail.

What I am looking for is a way for the code to carry on waiting X even though processEmail is happening in another thread but currently the code just waits for the thread to finish before waiting for X to happen again.

```
if X happens:
    thread = Thread(target = processEmail.main())
    thread.start()
```

FYI I have nothing that requires the output of processEmail.main() further down the code therefore there is no need for me to wait for its output.

Comment: it doesn't wait unless you `join`. You must have a `thread.join()` somewhere right? you'd need to show us a little more of your code.

Comment: So I had a `thread.join()` after `thread.start()` but i removed it because that is it appears that join makes it wait. But it is still waiting even without `thread.join()`

Comment: You don't run `processEmail.main()` in separate thread, because you call it before the thread even starts.

Comment: @GennadyKandaurov I figured that out exactly at the same time. Everyone gets caught by this once in a while :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Problem is that you're actually *calling* your method when passing it as argument of `Thread`.

So it executes, but in the current thread, that's why it's working but it's blocking (and since it probably returns `None`, you get no error from the `Thread` object, it just blocks)

Remove parentheses to pass the function object, not the result from the call!

```
thread = Thread(target = processEmail.main)
thread.start()
```

Note: some IDEs like PyCharm automatically add parentheses to function names. That's a bad idea in that case :)

Comment: Well damn, you are completely right! How I missed that I don't know!! Thank you very much Jean!