# How NOT to wait for a thread to finish in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41564930/python-how-to-not-wait-for-a-thread-to-finish-to-carry-on), he actually asked something like what I want. Except that the answer was to remove the parentheses. However if I remove the parentheses, then I'll not be able to pass arguments for my functions.

How can I do the following simple code without waiting:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def whatever(i):
  sleep(5)
  print("Hey! It's me number " + str(i))

for i in range(3):
  t = threading.Thread(target=whatever(i))
  t.start()
```

Desired output would be

```
Hey! It's me number 0
Hey! It's me number 1
Hey! It's me number 2
```

**All printed at the same time**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread), `target` should be a callable:

> target is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method

You are not passing your function to `target`, you are passing the return value of your function, so the function runs as soon as you pass it to `threading.Thread`, not when you call `t.start()`.

You should be using the `args` parameter to specify arguments to your callable.

Simply change this line:

```
 t = threading.Thread(target=whatever(i))
```

to

```
t = threading.Thread(target=whatever, args=(i,))
```

Answer (score 2):

you seem to not realize what this line does: `t = threading.Thread(target=whatever(i))` , removing the parenthesis is not simply to not wait for the thread to finish its so you can actually **start** the function in a seperate thread:

`target` should be the function object itself, but when you do `t = threading.Thread(target=whatever(1))` , the `target` will be the return value of `whatever` that you already ran in your original thread, you need to give `threading` the function itself then specify the parameters seperately and it will call it for you like this:

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def whatever(i):
  sleep(5)
  print("Hey! It's me number " + str(i))

for i in range(3):
  t = threading.Thread(target=whatever, args=(i,))
  t.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def whatever(i):
  print("Hey! It's me number " + str(i))

for i in range(3):
  t = threading.Thread(target=whatever, args=(i,))
  t.start()
```

You have to consider one thing though.

In Python we have something called GIL - Global Interpreter Lock. It's something that, in short, makes it possible for only one thread of your python application, to execute in a given interpreter at once. What does it mean?

That it's not quite that easy do achieve true concurrency in Python - while it may seem like the instructions are being executed simultaneously because of the super quick CPUs we have today, they are, in fact, not.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it into a lambda.

```
from time import sleep
import threading

def whatever(i):
  sleep(5)
  print("Hey! It's me number " + str(i))

for i in range(3):
  t = threading.Thread(target=lambda: whatever(i))
  t.start()
```